Error: Cannot find module '../controllers/userController' in Express.js Application
I am working on a full-stack project using Express.js for the backend and MongoDB for the database. I am encountering an error when trying to start my server. The error message is as follows:
Error: Cannot find module '../controllers/userController'
Require stack:
- D:\comun\dev_project\eHub\server\src\routes\userRoutes.js
- D:\comun\dev_project\eHub\server\src\app.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\comun\dev_project\eHub\server\src\routes\userRoutes.js:3:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'D:\\comun\\dev_project\\eHub\\server\\src\\routes\\userRoutes.js',
    'D:\\comun\\dev_project\\eHub\\server\\src\\app.js'
  ]
}

Here is my project structure:
server/
├── src/
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── controllers/
│   │   └── userController.js
│   ├── models/
│   │   └── User.js
│   ├── routes/
│   │   └── userRoutes.js
│   ├── services/
│   └── .env
├── package.json

src/app.js:
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

// Load environment variables from .env file
dotenv.config();

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
}).then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

const app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());

// Routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/userRoutes'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

src/routes/userRoutes.js:
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');

router.post('/', userController.createUser);
router.get('/', userController.getUsers);

module.exports = router;

src/controllers/userController.js:
const User = require('../models/User');

exports.createUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const newUser = new User({ name, email, password });
    await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).json(newUser);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};

exports.getUsers = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find();
    res.json(users);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};

src/models/User.js:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

I have double-checked the file paths and names to ensure there are no typos. Despite this, I still receive the "Cannot find module" error.

try adding a .js to the filename.  const userController = require('../controllers/userController.js');

I can't reproduce your problem.  All the files are required correctly when I try your code.  Are you using npm?  yarn?

Option A - You can try adding .js to the back of the import, as in:
const userController = require('../controllers/userController.js');

Option B - If this does not work, you can try to create a new file with a different name in the controller folder, then copy the contents of userController.js into it. Use the new file and see if that helps.
Option C - Try to restart your IDE.

Hi, I've tried them all but still getting the same error. I don't know what could be the problem.

Wow. That is quite interesting. Are you absolutely sure about your path?

yh I've checked it several times, I was thinking, it could be the way I'm exporting the modules
